# Unable to mock Spring-Data-JPA repositories with Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write tests for a service. But I am unsuccessful at mocking the `repository` dependency. Other non-repository dependencies are successfully mocked. The repository instance is always the actual implementation and not a mock instance.

I am using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA to build the application. Mockito is used for mocking. I managed to distil the problem into a test project. The complete test project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/ChrisZhong/spring-boot-data-jpa-mockito-testing). Below are snippets of code from the test project; the following is the `PersonServiceTest` class.

**Update 1:** `before()` code should be checking `personRepository` not `personService`

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(App.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({ServletTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class, TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.class})
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles({"mock-some-bean", "mock-person-repository"})
public class PersonServiceTest {

    @Inject
    private SomeBean someBean;
    @Inject
    private PersonRepository personRepository;
    @Inject
    private PersonService personService;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        assertThat(mockingDetails(someBean).isMock(), is(true));
        assertThat(mockingDetails(personRepository).isMock(), is(true));
    }

    @Test
    public void doSomething() throws Exception { ... }
}
```

The test class uses two profiles: `mock-some-bean` and `mock-person-repository`. Basically, I am using profiles to determine what should be mocked. Before doing any tests, I assert that the `someBean` and `personService` are mocked instances. `someBean` is mocked properly but `personService` always fails. The following code is the code from the `TestConfig` class.

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestConfig.class);

    @Bean
    @Profile("mock-some-bean")
    public SomeBean someBean() {
        logger.info("Mocking: {}", SomeBean.class);
        return mock(SomeBean.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("mock-person-repository")
    public PersonRepository personRepository() {
        logger.info("Mocking: {}", PersonRepository.class);
        return mock(PersonRepository.class);
    }
}
```

**Update 2:** question made clearer

What am I missing? It appears that Spring Data JPA is always creating an instance and ignoring the `@Bean` defined in the `TestConfig` class. How do I "tell" Spring Data JPA not to create an instance? I appreciate any help I can get to resolve this problem.

**Update 3:** still looking for ideal solution

I would still appreciate a solution. Although I have marked the solution as accepted, the suggested solution is not ideal. Because there are varying levels of integration tests (from end-to-end testing to a very narrow scope of testing with a small set of dependencies).

Comment: Once the spring-jpa bean is injected, spy that object instead of mocking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few issues here. I assume that you're trying to verify if `PersonRepository` is mocked or not. However, in your test you wrote:

```
assertThat(mockingDetails(personService).isMock(), is(true));
```

You're not mocking `PersonService` so it makes sense that it would fail this assertion.

---

Another issue is that Spring Data JPA will also create a bean called `personRepository`. So your mocked repository bean will be ignored unless you change its name:

```
@Bean
@Profile("mock-person-repository")
// Change method name to change bean name
public PersonRepository personRepositoryMock() {
    logger.info("Mocking: {}", PersonRepository.class);
    return mock(PersonRepository.class);
}
```

But if you do that, then there will be two beans of the type `PersonRepository`, so autowiring it into your service will fail. To fix that you would have to prevent it from creating the repositories with Spring Data JPA.

---

Anyhow, a much cleaner solution would be to use `MockitoJUnitRunner` in stead of Springs test runner. All you would have to do is annotate the class you want to test with `@InjectMocks` and all dependencies you want to mock and inject with `@Mock`: like this:

```
@InjectMocks
private PersonService personService;
@Mock
private SomeBean someBean;
@Mock
private PersonRepository repository;
```

And then you can delete `TestConfig` and remove all annotations on your test and replace them with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I made some mistakes, it should have been checking `PersonRepository` not `PersonService`. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Switching to `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` may not be an ideal solution for the actual implementation because (1) all dependencies of a service have to be explicitly mocked and (2) `@InjectMocks` fail silently if it cannot mock any dependencies.

Comment: (1) True, but that allows you to narrow the scope to a single class in stead of testing multiple classes at once. (2) If that's a problem, then you can autowire using a constructor and manually create an instance of your service in your tests, like explained here: https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/